# Need some advice on inserting a cropped image to the original one on Android

Tags: java, android

This a code I got from a tutorial. It opens the gallery or camera to load an image, then using the default android image editor, crops the image then sends the cropped image back to the activity. What I wanna do is I want to send  the whole image to the activity from the gallery, while the cropped image is inserted to a new ImageView or Button with the matching scale and coordinates from its original, sort of like blending in. Basically, like an app that selects a part of an image, then turns the selected part into something like a button while still being in the original image

```
package dev.edmt.androidcropimage;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView imageView;
Toolbar toolbar;
File file;
Uri uri;
Intent CamIntent,GalIntent,CropIntent;
final int RequestPermissionCode=1;
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics;
int width,height;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Crop Image");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    if(permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
        RequestRuntimePermission();
}

private void RequestRuntimePermission() {
    if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.CAMERA))
        Toast.makeText(this,"CAMERA permission allows us to access CAMERA app",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},RequestPermissionCode);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.btn_camera)
        CameraOpen();
    else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.btn_gallery)
        GalleryOpen();
    return true;
}

private void GalleryOpen() {
    GalIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(GalIntent,"Select Image from Gallery"),2);
}

private void CameraOpen() {
    CamIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "file"+String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())+".jpg");
    uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    CamIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,uri);
    CamIntent.putExtra("return-data",true);
    startActivityForResult(CamIntent,0);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if(requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
       CropImage();
    else if(requestCode == 2)
   {
       if(data != null)
       {
           uri = data.getData();
           CropImage();
       }
   }
    else if (requestCode == 1)
   {
       if(data != null)
       {
           Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
           Bitmap bitmap = bundle.getParcelable("data");
           imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
       }
   }
}
```

I'm guessing these scale the cropped image

```
  private void CropImage() {

    try{
        CropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        CropIntent.setDataAndType(uri,"image/*");



        CropIntent.putExtra("crop","true");
        CropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        CropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        CropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 128);
        CropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 128);
        CropIntent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded",false);
        CropIntent.putExtra("return-data",true);

        startActivityForResult(CropIntent,1);
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex)
    {

    }

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case RequestPermissionCode:
        {
            if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                Toast.makeText(this,"Permission Granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(this,"Permission Canceled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Try not to use `com.android.camera.action.CROP`. Instead of this build your own cropper or you can use a 3rd party library.

Comment: I considered using another library however, I don't really understand how they get the image data since the two I've searched use their own activity, much like how this uses the default Android editor

Comment: Yeah, testing them currently. I still don't know how to capture the original image and transfer it somewhere

Comment: The app's goal is to upload a picture, crop a part of it while keeping the original image intact. The cropped part then becomes a functional button for other purposes

My logic to this problem was->crop the image using a 3rd party library->obtain both the original image and the cropped image. I was thinking of making two imageViews, one for the original and one for the cropped part however it seems I'm making things harder for myself. And I don't know how to manipulate 3rd party library data

Comment: Yeah, I did. I don't know what's the function of this line

         Rect rect = cropImageView.getCropRect();
         cropImageView.setImageBitmap();